# Ternary operator javascript

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code?
if I call this function without any arguments, the expected output is "critical" instead "medium" is returned.

```
let labelBlock = (label="") =>{
        label = label.toLowerCase();
        const txt = label == "high" ? "High" : "medium" ? "Medium" : "Critical";
        return `<span class="${txt.toLowerCase()}">${txt}</span>`;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

`label` is empty at the start. The first condition `label == "high"` is false and in the second condition you have `"medium"`, which, in Js, is truthy value hence `"Medium"` is set.

You can change that line to the following to get `Critical`. See change (`label == "medium"`)

```
const txt = label == "high" ? "High" : label == "medium" ? "Medium" : "Critical";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace "medium" with "label == 'medium'".

```
let labelBlock = (label="") =>{
    label = label.toLowerCase();
    const txt = label == "high" ? "High" : label == "medium" ? "Medium" : "Critical";
    return `<span class="${txt.toLowerCase()}">${txt}</span>`;
}
```

"medium" expression in the second part is always "true" in your code. So the second ternary operator always returns the first value ("Medium").

Answer (score 1):

There is no condition which is evaluated at the second part `"medium" ? "Medium" : "Critical";`

Hope this works for you

```js
        const txt = label == "high" ? "High" : label == "medium" ? "Medium" : "Critical";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary operation meaning is below. As you can see the problem is you are checking `if ("medium")`.

```
  var txt;
  if (label == "high") {
    txt = "High";
  } else {
    if ("medium") {
      text = "Medium";
    } else {
      text = "Critical";
    }
  }
```